# PHP: FedEx Web Services

Tags: php, web-services, fedex

I'm trying to track a number that uses FedEx, but I can't get the series of events shown as in the website. I'm using the Track Web Services and using a Test Key. I'm currently using

```
$response->CompletedTrackDetails->TrackDetails->Events
```

which only gives me the first step (out of a total of 9). Please, what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're parsing the XML response, but you need to loop thru TrackReply->TrackDetails->Events

Something like this...

```
$ScanCount = substr_count ($Response, '<Events>') ;
$xmlresult = xml2array($Response);

if ( $ScanCount > 1 ) {

for ( $i=0 ; $i < $ScanCount ; $i++) {
    $status=$xmlresult['TrackReply']['TrackDetails']['Events'][$i]['EventDescription']['value'];
// addl parsing...
}
}
```